# How can I pass additional parameters to database connection in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to connect my Lumen app to an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance. In order to do so, I need to pass "sslmode" and "sslrootcert" parameters to the database connection.

In Laravel, I could serve them through an additional "options" array inside config/database.php. Since there is no config/database.php file in Lumen, how can I pass them?

Comment: Behind the scenes there is a config/database.php file that defines the connections. I believe you can override these by creating your own config/database.php from the root of the project. You can add your Postgres config as you would in Laravel.

Comment: Creating my own config/database.php in the root of the project solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lumen still uses config files behind the scenes. There is a config/database.php file in the framework root that defines the connections. You can override these by creating your own config/database.php from the root of the project. You can add your Postgres config as you would in Laravel.